# Under ‘create new project’ the ‘use current project as is’ button is greyed out. How do I fix this please?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, mergin-maps

In Mergin Maps on QGIS, under ‘create new project’ the ‘use current project as is’ button is greyed out. It worked first time but then I deleted my project via Mergin Maps website because I made some changes on QGIS. Since then, the button has been greyed out. I have tried uninstalling then reinstalling the plugin (which caused a ‘broken plugin’ error, though I have now reinstalled via download), but that has not resolved the ‘use current project as is’ issue. I have also tried closing then reopening a new Mergin Maps account, but that has not resolved things either. Is there some way to upload my QGIS project to Mergin Maps again?

Answer (score 2):

If you open the project in your file browser and enable Show hidden files in your browser, you should be able to see a hidden folder (.mergin).

You need to delete that folder and repeat the process in QGIS.

Feel free to contact support@merginmaps.com for further support.